# Grails 4: Mail plugin fails to read 'password' property when running on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, grails-plugin

My Grails 4 application runs fine locally but fails to send emails when I run it in Elastic Beanstalk.  I'm using the runnable WAR file on Java 11 platform using the embedded (not external) Tomcat server.

I'm setting the `grails.mail.password` property externally via a `GRAILS_MAIL_PASSWORD` environment variable.
[image]

I'm checking the config value in `BootStrap.groovy` and in the `EmailsService`, and the value is properly set.

#### BootStrap

```
class BootStrap {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        String config = "\n"
        grailsApplication.config.each {
            config += " --> $it.key : ${grailsApplication.config.getProperty(it.key)}\n"
        }
        log.info(config)
```

[image]

#### EmailService

```
class EmailService {

    @Value('${cloudcard.email.doNotSend}')
    boolean doNotSend

    @Value('${grails.mail.username}')
    String grailsMailUsername

    @Value('${grails.mail.password}')
    String grailsMailPassword

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        log.info("grailsMailUsername: ${grailsMailUsername.take(2)}****${grailsMailUsername.reverse().take(2).reverse()}")
        log.info("grailsMailPassword: ${grailsMailPassword.take(4)}****${grailsMailPassword.reverse().take(4).reverse()}")
    }
```

#### EmailService Log Output

```
Nov 16 02:48:32 ip-172-31-31-36 web: 2021-11-16 02:48:32.946  INFO --- [io-5000-exec-10] us.cloudcard.api.EmailService            : grailsMailUsername: AK****G2
Nov 16 02:48:32 ip-172-31-31-36 web: 2021-11-16 02:48:32.946  INFO --- [io-5000-exec-10] us.cloudcard.api.EmailService            : grailsMailPassword: BI****5Z
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: 2021-11-16 02:48:33.311 ERROR --- [pool-4-thread-1] grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder   : Failed to send email
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 
failed to connect, no password specified?
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender$send$0.call(Unknown Source)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:124)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:399)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:486)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:400)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437)
Nov 16 02:48:33 ip-172-31-31-36 web: ... 22 common frames omitted
```

## But...

...if I hardcode the username and password into `application.groovy`, everything works, and I receive the email in my inbox.  I'm not sure if it matters, but this is one of the only things I have configured in `application.groovy`. Almost everything else is in `application.yml`.

Do you have any idea why the Grails Mail Plugin might be ignoring my external config?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I've redeployed the same application using the external Tomcat container platform (Amazon Linux 2; Tomcat 8.5; Corretto Java 11) and the application is now respecting the environment variables.